# QMap::contains() not returning expected value

Tags: c++, qt, qmap

I have a class that contains a QMap object:

```
QMap<QString, Connection*> users;
```

Now, in the following function Foo(), the if clause always returns false but when I iterate through the map, the compared QString, i.e., str1 is present in the keys.

```
void Foo(QString& str1, QString& str2)
{    
    if(users.contains(str1))
        users[str1]->doStuff(str2);
    else
    {
        for(QMap<QString, Connection>::iterator iter = users.begin(); 
                           iter!= users.end();iter++)
            qDebug()<<iter.key();
    }
}
```

Am I doing something wrong? Why doesn't contains() return true ?

Comment: Is there a typo in your question?  You say that `str2` is present in the keys, but you're checking if `users` contains `str1`.

Comment: I've done the required editing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With unicode, two strings may be rendered the same but actually be different.  Assuming that's the case you'll want to [normalize](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qstring.html#normalized) the strings first:

```
str = str.normalize(QString::NormalizationForm_D);
if (users.contains(str))
    // do something useful
```

Of course, you'll need to normalize the string before you put it in your users map as well.

Comment: Even after normalizing the QString before storing in the QMap and before checking, contains() returns false only.

Comment: Please show us in what way the strings are different. For example, `qDebug() << str.toUtf8()` should show us the actual bytes that create the string.

Comment: After cleaning the project and rebuilding, it worked. Thanks.